# http keep-alive behavior - how to handle closed server socket?

Tags: .net, sockets, http, tcp, keep-alive

I want to understand how keep-alive should be handled, specifically the "case" when servers close the keep-alive connection because of a timeout or an artificial limits of requests processed using a single socket.
I understand that the read from a closed socket will return 0. What should the client do in this case? Does it try to open a new connection?

The below test code does periodically performs http requests:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://192.168.1.22/api/v1/system/status/", cancellationToken);
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HttpClientGetStatus- Exception - " + ex.GetType() + " " + ex.Message);
    }
   Thread.Sleep(this.StatusFreq * 1000);
}
```

When the socket is closed by the server, I don't see any exceptions. Does it mean that when client tries to open a new socket internally and as long as it works, nothing [regarding an old socket being closed a new one being open instead] is returned to the user? Where can I find specifications or any kind or perhaps an article describing the correct http keep-alive behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP persistent connections are explained in details in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

However in your case you don't have to worry about socket management because the [.Net HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) library handles (and hides) all this low-level stuff. That's why you don't get any exception related to socket reuse.

Comment: I accepted the answer. Thank you. Just to clarify, did I understand correctly that when a socket is closed, the client library retries the request?

Comment: @MosheShmukler yes, I think so

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find specifications or any kind or perhaps an article describing the correct http keep-alive behavior?

[RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) section 8.1 deals with persistent connetions and especially section 8.1.4 "Practical Considerations" is relevant to your question. To cite:

> A client, server, or proxy MAY close the transport connection at any
>      time. ... clients, servers, and proxies MUST be able to recover
>      from asynchronous close events. Client software SHOULD reopen the
>      transport connection and retransmit the aborted sequence of requests
>      without user interaction so long as the request sequence is
>      idempotent (see section 9.1.2)...

In other words: If the client detects a server-side close before sending a request it should simply open a new connection for the next request. If it detects the close during sending a request it should restart with a new connection only for idempotent requests.